# Why doesn't Try/Catch work within number types?

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

```
Dim mynumber as Integer 'This is the variable as an integer, (Integers only allow WHOLE numbers)

Console.WriteLine("Enter your number..") 'Ask to enter number
    Try
        mynumber = Console.ReadLine 'Read user input and store it
    Catch
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
        Console.WriteLine("Only whole numbers allowed! Press enter to start again!")
        Console.ResetColor()
        Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Clear()
        GoTo start
    End Try
```

Okay guys, As you can see from the example above I have set up a a Try/Catch for error handling. I have come across a problem. YES the Try/Catch code prevents letters (strings) from being entered in but when I enter a decimal number it still accepts it. Why? And How can this be prevented? A decimal number is not meant to be accepted because an integer only accepts whole numbers!

Thanks.

Comment: I think that the above case is a bad example of exception handling. `Try/Catch` blocks should be used to catch *unexpected* errors. It's obvious that user can enter invalid data, so this should be handled in an `IF...THEN` block. Also make sure to use most specific type when catching an exception. `Catch ex As Exception` will just eat whatever error it encounters. `Catch ex As InvalidCastException` would be better, it shows that you know which kind error is expected to happen.

Comment: @Neolisk, Ahh.. This is really complicated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an implicit conversion between numeric types and thus an error is not triggered. There are different ways to know the exact numeric type. I guess that the best option here is something on the lines of the following code:

```
Dim mynumber0 As Double 'This is the variable as an integer, (Integers only allow WHOLE numbers)
Dim wasOK As Boolean = True
Console.WriteLine("Enter your number..") 'Ask to enter number
Try
    mynumber0 = Console.ReadLine 'Read user input and store it
    If (Convert.ToInt32(mynumber0) <> mynumber0) Then
        wasOK = False
    End If
Catch
    wasOK = False
End Try

Dim mynumber As Integer = mynumber0
If (Not wasOK) Then
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
    Console.WriteLine("Only whole numbers allowed! Press enter to start again!")
    Console.ResetColor()
    Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Clear()
    GoTo start
End If
```

UPDATE

`TryParse` alternative, as suggested by mafafu

```
Dim mynumber As Integer 'This is the variable as an integer, (Integers only allow WHOLE numbers)
Console.WriteLine("Enter your number..") 'Ask to enter number
If (Not Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine, mynumber)) Then
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
    Console.WriteLine("Only whole numbers allowed! Press enter to start again!")
    Console.ResetColor()
    Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Clear()
    GoTo start
End If
```

Comment: You could also use a Integer.TryParse() there which would return false if the input is has any decimal places.

Comment: @mafafu, Could you please give a quick example?

Comment: @varocarbas, Thanks, Seems like alot of code for something little. Isn't there a quicker/easier way of doing this?

Comment: @mafafu Thanks. I will include it into my answer to account for all the options.

Comment: And then if false, `Throw New Exception("Not an Integer!")` so you get to the catch block without a boolean status. I mean, maybe. Either way works.

Comment: @Tahmid I personally don't tryParse too much but will update my answer and you can choose. I have written a clear and adaptable enough structure (what I always prefer), but I can do it shorter.

Comment: @Tahmid There you have it Tahmid. It is not as nicely-structured as mine but I have to recognise that in this specific context seems more adequate.

Comment: @mafafu I have included your suggestion in my answer. I tend to avoid TryParse but this time seemed a better solution (actually this is what I usually utilise for console but today I was too form-focused :))

Comment: @varocarbas, Thank you! Much appreciated! I have 1 more question. Can you also use `Not String.TryParse` to only get a input of a string?

Comment: @Tahmid You are welcome. Regarding your las question: try it yourself :) ... String type does not have the TryParse extension method. The reason is easy: nothing would trigger a false; any input is assumed to be a string by default: "5" is a string, "5.5" is a string and "string" is a string.

Answer (score 2):

As has been written, you can use Integer.TryParse to check if a number can be parsed to an Integer. Also, you really should use **Option Strict On**, which will help Visual Studio point out problems in VB.NET code.

My take on an answer:

```
Option Strict On

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim myNumber As Integer 'This is the variable as an integer, (Integers only allow WHOLE numbers)
        Dim userInput As String
        Dim userInputValid As Boolean = False

        While Not userInputValid
            Console.Write("Enter your number.. ") 'Ask to enter number

            userInput = Console.ReadLine() 'Read user input and store it
            userInputValid = Integer.TryParse(userInput, myNumber)
            If Not userInputValid Then
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
                Console.WriteLine("Only whole numbers allowed! Press enter to start again!")
                Console.ResetColor()
                Console.ReadLine()
                Console.Clear()
            End If

        End While

        Console.WriteLine("I got the number " & myNumber.ToString())
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

**Edit:** Please see the section "To set the Option Strict default setting for new projects" at [Option Strict Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

With Option Strict Off, VB.NET tries to behave like older versions of VB which had rather loosy-goosy rules with regard to type-checking.  Strings, floating-point types, and integer types could largely be used interchangeably, and trying to assign a floating-point value to an integer type would round it somehow (I forget the exact details).  While there are a few very rare cases where Option Strict Off can be useful for purposes other than giving old VB6 code a chance to maybe work, only someone who is expert enough to understand the intricacies of such cases should even consider using it at all in any new code (and even then only for the very small pieces where it could be helpful).

It's important to note, by the way, that even VB.NET regards a conversion from a floating-point value to an integer type as being "successful" if rounding the floating-point value to the nearest integer would yield a value which is representable in that type, even if the floating-point value had a non-zero fractional part which got dropped during the conversion.  I don't like that design (I think if one wants the `Int32` nearest a given floating-point value, one should use a function that says that) but it is what it is.